# how to know the data size returned from mysql server with connector-j

Tags: java, mysql, performance, connector-j

I am using mysql with connector-j from java to perform a query. I would like to know the size of the data returned when I use it with/without compression.
What is the best way to obtain the total amount of data passed from the server to the client?

The code I am using works with `PreparedStatement` and `ResultSet`:

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
    function.apply(rs);
}
```

Can I obtain the amount of data in Java?
Is there any external way to get it?

Comment: What is the relevance of you mentioning "when I use it with/without compression" ? What compression? And what data? All you show is a snippet that does things and stuff with a resultset, not specific data inside it. Are you perhaps pulling some image from the database or something?

Comment: no images, just strings. the compression is built-in in connector-j. it is zlib compression.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it like that:

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

while (rs.next()) {
    function.apply(rs);
    sb.append(<your_data>);
}

double len = sb.toString().length() / 1024;
```

Comment: can I get the row size? and what if it is compressed?

Comment: What I meant was that you need to add all the line value as a String to the StringBuffer and then check it's size